# is there a paid version of microsoft online viewer

Tags: office365

I can use the MS online viewer for viewing word docs in an IFrame like this:

```
const frame: HTMLIFrameElement = document.querySelector('iframe');

frame.src = `https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=${url}`;
```

I am using azure storage so my url will expire over time.

The only thing is that this is an unprotected free service and it states when you first load that it might show adds etc.

Is there a paid service that is more secure and won't show advertisements?

Answer (score 1):

From my research, it shows that there isn't a current existing version of Microsoft Online Viewer, but only free browser-based and app-based tools.

There is an app version of the browser software here that might work: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/doc-viewer/9n69kfjds28z?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

My second recommendation would be to just use a more secure cloud-based service where you can enter your information online without ads. In that case, Office 365 has a decent online viewer built-in and I've never experienced ads while using it. You'd have to pay for the license/ownership of the entire Office 365 Suite, however.